# How to delete a Trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I create some Triggers like the following for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_USER
BEFORE INSERT ON HOUSE_USER
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.USER_ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT SEQ_USER_ID.NEXTVAL
    INTO :NEW.USER_ID FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

But i cant drop them. When i try to drop it:

```
DROP TRIGGER TRIGGER_USER;
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-04080: trigger 'TRIGGER_USER' does not exist
```

I found out that you have to tell the schema. I fired the following Command:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TRIGGERS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'HOUSE_USER'
```

It Delivered:

```
OWNER: APEX
TRIGGER_NAME: TRIGGER_USER
```

So i tried again with:

```
DROP TRIGGER APEX.TRIGGER_USER;
```

But i again got the error:

```
ORA-04080: trigger 'TRIGGER_USER' does not exist
```

**So:** how can i delete triggers?

Comment: Can you post the actual output from `all_triggers`?  At least the `owner` and `trigger_name`?  My guess is that you created an object with a case-sensitive identifier but your example isn't doing that...

Comment: i upadted my post. owner is `APEX` und trigger_name is `TRIGGER_USER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably simply don't have the right to drop trigger from `APEX` user.

Make sure to grant `DROP ANY TRIGGER`.

The error message "does not exist" may lead to confusion as it does exist, just not accessible for the user.